# Programmatically replace 4 whitespace at the start of each line in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have string like

```
    try (EchoClient echoClient = EchoClient.create()) {
      EchoRequest request =
          EchoRequest.newBuilder().setName().setPoint().setLoooooongNameWithTest().build();
      EchoResponse response = echoClient.echo(request);
    }
```

I need to remove the first 4 white space. Like:

```
try (EchoClient echoClient = EchoClient.create()) {
  EchoRequest request =
      EchoRequest.newBuilder().setName().setPoint().setLoooooongNameWithTest().build();
  EchoResponse response = echoClient.echo(request);
}
```

My approach is to split string by line-breaker and replace the first 4 white space use regex.

```
String[] codes = doc.split("\\r?\\n");
for (int i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
  codes[i] = codes[i].replaceFirst("^( ){4}", "");
}
String result = String.join("\n", codes);
```

I wonder if you have any better solution to solve this. Or any way to replace 4 whitespace without loops each line.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do that in single method call as `doc = doc.replaceFirst("(?m)^ {4}", "");` or check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/XwU1NQ/1

Comment: If you're using Java 11+, you can just use the stripLeading() method to remove the leading whitespaces from each of your array elements (i.e. lines of the string). https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripLeading()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in single method call with `MULTILINE` mode as:

```
doc = doc.replaceAll("(?m)^ {4}", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XwU1NQ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable inline `MULTILINE` mode so that `^` can be matched after line breaks or start
- `^ {4}`: Match exactly 4 spaces at the start of a line

Comment: we should use replaceAll here.

Comment: Oh yes, it should be `replaceAll` to replace in all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all 4 starting whitespaces on new line like below.

```java
String s = //your text here
s.replaceAll("(?m)^ {4}", "");
```

Comment: This will remove line breaker as well. But thanks anyway.

Comment: finding regex replaced with @anubhava finding regex. That's better way.